# Property owned and sold by SDIRA holding note

Tags: real-estate, self-directed-ira

My LLC/SDIRA sold a property and is seller financing, so the mortgage payment is going right back into the SDIRA account. I have been told that that is not a permitted transaction by another investor and I am going to be penalized. Is this so, and is there any way for me to fix it?
That actually is not the sticky part. The person that purchased the property is now involved with one of my children. They would like to refinance the property with a lender with both of them on the title & mortgage. Is that allowed? That seems a little to close to breaking the rules to me. Is that an allowable transaction? Can anyone provided insight before I hire legal counsel?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-prohibited-transactions